# animate.css failing with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

So I'm in the process of making a sing along animation with jquery. I managed to make a jquery script that makes the font colors swap between four different colors I chose and then append that new information to a div.

The next thing I want to do is make the words/letters bounce along to the music and to do it I chose animate.css because it was lightweight and easy to use. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't seem to work when added to my dynamically created text. The text color works and it seems to apply the correct classes and properties to the letters/words yet it never seems to actually bounce. Any ideas?

```
//fade out the sugar skull div
$(function () {
  $('.sugarskull').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).delay(15000).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});

//js script to rotate colors on font
$('.lyrics').each(function() {
  var letters = $(this).text().split('');
  var colors = ["#e72f14", "#f59f00;", "#ea4591", "#2a94c7"];
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  //animated bounce class is specific to the animate.css library and 
//should make the letters bounce but fails
    letters[i] = "<span class = 'animated bounce' style='color:" + 
colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";'>" + letters[i] + "</span>";
  }
  $(this).html(letters.join(""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding **animation bounce** to span.

so the span element should have below css to work the animations::

```
span {position: relative; display: block;}
```

Comment: Gave that a shot but it actually made each letter a block element which is definitely not what I want. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that I'm getting content dynamically.

Comment: Okay than add display: inline-block;

Comment: Hey Sonia, so my friend and I have been doing some testing on this and we seemed to have come to the conclusion that the css library doesn't function on dyanimcally created content. We aren't sure why this is so I'll just hard code it myself. I did try an inline block but it didn't seem to help :(

Comment: Thankyou Grace! But anyway if you could send me link I could have helped you in a better way

Comment: OR else you could just try adding css by jquery itself. Maybe that may help you guys

Comment: Hi Sonia, I can send you the github if you'd like to give it a shot

Comment: Yes I would love to help you Grace! Just contacting you via your profile link

Comment: Hi Sonia, not sure how to contact you on your page but here is the github link! https://github.com/gasulliv/cocosingalong